# The requested URL was not found on this server in cordova for the facebook plugin in react?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, facebook-login

[image]i actually used the facebook login npm in react and i tried on my browser it works when i run on ios devices using cordova,it shows the following error
Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server.
i don't know how to fix this? can anyone help me.here my samples

```
<FacebookLogin
                       appId="XXXXX682921631"
                       language="en_US"
                       scope="public_profile,email"
                       callback={this.responseFacebook}
                       xfbml={true}
                       fields="id,email,name"
                       cookie={true}
                       version="v2.10"
                       className="facebook-login"
                       textButton="Login With Facebook"/>
```

and i use my http://localhost:8080/ it works on browser and i ain't know about the mobile what to give and where to give